# Sum Backbone Collection

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

I've already read some topics here in stackoverflow, but I didn't found a solution to my problem...
I want do the sum of 'progress' field in all my models into a collection...
So in my collection file I have:

```
  progressTotal: ->
    total = _.reduce(@, ((memo, value) ->
      memo + value.get('progress')
    ), 0)
    return total
```

But I get that value is undefined ... why ? I've taken inspiration from here: [Getting the sum of a collection (all models) with backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722048/getting-the-sum-of-a-collection-all-models-with-backbone-js) but the solution doesn't work for me.

Any suggestion ? thank you

**EDIT:** Seems like if progress is a string...but in my db is a integer.

Comment: You can do memo +  +value.get('progress') - to cast the string to an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an array of `models` to `reduce` instead of collection, so just replace `@` with `@models`

```
progressTotal: ->
    total = _.reduce(@models, ((memo, value) ->
      memo + value.get('progress')
    ), 0)
    return total
```

you can also use `Backbone.Collection#reduce` method

```
progressTotal: ->
    return @reduce(((memo, value) ->
      memo + value.get('progress')
    ), 0)
```

Comment: I had already tried with the Backbone.Collection#reduce and I've also used your code, but when I do: console.log @milestones.progressTotal() I get NaN.

Comment: I've also tried to print the value directly in the function: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/30dde77281c813461a32 I always get NaN.

Comment: The answer is correct...I have a problem but it related to my collection...I will open a new question here on Stackoverflow if I didn't fix by myself. Thank you.